# Rev Slider Layers not showing on Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider, revolution-slider

I'm using Revolution Slider - I'm working on a laptop (but it's the *HP revolve* - so I think it's considered a Tablet).

My slider is working ... but the layers (shapes and Text) are not showing up on my pc.  They show up fine on my friends desktop though.

http://www.canadianseafoods.ca/newsite/

Any ideas what's going on?

Edit: it's just in chrome.

Comment: The slider gets disabled when the used browser doesn't run or support Javascript. Your HP Revolve might not support Javascript or it might be turned off.

Comment: No, Javascript is fine.

Comment: I can't help you then. What I did is opened the website in Chrome and it was ok. As soon as I turned off Javascript the whole slider disappeared. However, I see that your issue that elements within the slider are disappearing. Are there any errors in the Dev tools console on that pc?

Comment: I don't know, honestly.    http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7d75949

Comment: It could definitely be caused by these errors. You should try to fix them first.

Comment: okay ... i'll google it and see what it tell me to do.

Comment: I think it might be a jquery conflict ... cause Rev Slider has it's own jQurey ... right? ... I"m sorry ... i really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Okay ... it's only when the slider is in 'auto' ... so it's set to Full-width now ... and the text is showing on one slide only.   I've duplicated that slide ... but the text doesn't show up.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing this unfortunately. You could try contacting the makers of Revolution Slider, since I don't have any experience with using it. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue on Slider Revolution V6.4.6. Essentially with the image layer selected in the editor window, select the `Visibility` tab and ensure the image will be visible on the specific devise types available.

[image: Visibility Tab]

[image: Devise Types]